# How Method passing parameters behave in multi-threaded enviornment

Tags: java, multithreading

By definition Local variables are the variables declared within a method. Multiple threads  maintain them in their own stacks. I need to understand how this works with passing Method parameters in multi-threaded environment. ?

For example - assume User is a instance variable and pass to its local synchronized methods.

public static synchronized registerUser(User user,int count){}

public synchronized registerUser(User user,int count){}

In the above example , I am passing a Object and primitive.

1. How the passing parameters manage in static methods with multiple threads? (Objects,primitives)
2. How the passing parameters manage in non-static methods with multiple threads? (Objects,primitives) ?

3.Active thread always acquire the method lock that it executes. As User object reference is working under synchronized context will that reference available for other threads to use in     unlock methods?

Comment: Why should argument passing work any different in a multi-threaded environment than in a single-threaded one?

Comment: The first thing you need to understand is that a Java application is multithreaded whether you explicitly start threads or not. So the same rules apply one way or the other.

Answer (score 0):

The static method locks on the class, while the member method locks on the object.

Java uses a [pass-by-value](http://javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm), which in the case of a primitive is the value and in the case of an object is the reference to the object.

In your methods:

- there is no lock on the `user`, which could be modified by another thread via a different reference to it while the synchronized method being invoked.
- the value of the primitive `count` cannot be modified such that the method would see the modification after any method is invoked.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. In a case of Thread acquire the lock of "static" methods. How s the behavior. 1. Will this lock only the other synchronized static methods as well as this is a class level for other Threads ?

Comment: Yes, when a static method is synchronized it will not prevent another thread from invoking a instance method.  Take a look at this question for an example - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15329731/java-synchronizing-static-methods