# What is a Singleton instance synchronized on?

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronization, singleton

I have read that `synchronized void f() { /* body */ }` is equivalent to 
`void f() { synchronized (this) { /* body */ } }`.

So when we do a `synchronization` of a singleton's get method what object are we synchronizing on. Is it the **Class** or is it the **Object**?

```
public class YourObject {
    private static YourObject instance;

    private YourObject() { }

    public static synchronized YourObject getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new YourObject();
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Is this equivalent to -

```
public static YourObject getInstance() {
    synchronized (this) {
        /* body */
    }
}
```

or

```
public static YourObject getInstance() {
    synchronized (YourObject.class) {
        /* body */
    }
}
```

Comment: If method is static, Lock will be on classes `Class` object.

Comment: No, the class isn't static. Only the `getInstance()` method is.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java - synchronizing static methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15329731/java-synchronizing-static-methods)

Comment: @yadav_vi sorry, i meant method.

Comment: Since your first proposal doesn't even compile (or make sense), that pretty much pinpoints the answer, doesn't it?

Comment: There is no "this" in static context. Anyway, take a look at this article with good examples of singleton http://shipilev.net/blog/2014/safe-public-construction/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are obtaining lock at class level i.e. static method in your synchronized method, so synchronization on `YouObject.class` is equivalent to static method synchronization. Also you won't be able to refer to `this` in your static method as `this` refers to the current or *this* object.

So this:

```
public static synchronized YourObject getInstance() {
```

in above code is equivalent to

```
synchronized (YourObject.class) {
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's ask [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html):

> You might wonder what happens when a static synchronized method is
>   invoked, since a static method is associated with a class, not an
>   object. In this case, the thread acquires the intrinsic lock for the
>   Class object associated with the class. Thus access to class's static
>   fields is controlled by a lock that's distinct from the lock for any
>   instance of the class.

So:

```
public static YourObject getInstance() {
    synchronized (YourObject.class) {
        /* body */
    }
}
```

is equivalent to you code